# How to test response body in GO?

Tags: testing, go

I have the following function:

```
func SomeFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, ...) error{
 .
 .
 .
    return json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&c)
}
```

where c is my struct.
When I run the function I receive the response body with a json but I can't test this function. For example, I have:

```
func TestSomeFunction(t *testing.T) {
 .
 .
 .

    w := httptest.ResponseRecorder{}
    err := SomeFunction(w, ...)
 .
 .
}
```

My w.Body is empty in this case. The problem isn't my function because I when I run I get the body. I think I'm not testing in the right way. How is the right way to test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `httptest.NewRecorder()` to get your recorder.... additionally I wouldn't test against the recorder's `Bytes`.... check the `Result` https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder.Result